# EL Validation - How do I detect invalid EL from JSF xhtml in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, el

Many times, when I am developing, I start a JSF app and only when I hit the page, it detects some invalid EL value, or even worse, it's not interpreted and silently ignored, without any warning.

Is there any way to validate EL values from xhtml files with eclipse while writing the xhtml file?

ps. even a compile-time solution would be nice too.

Comment: @BalusC have you tested it? If yes, how fast/reliable is it?

Answer (score 0):

Had same question.

Try Window > Preference > Web > JavaServer Faces Tools > Validation > Identifier Resolution > Member not found... set it to Error.

This gave me at least give an error in the xhtml page when writing the EL expression wrong. However, it doesnt give an error when you refactor your manged beans in such a way that the EL expression get broken. Bit strange. There is probably another button somewhere to initialize JSF/EL validation on  xhtml pages when changing java-files/managed beans to fix it, but havnt found it.